# Google Script sleep timer

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, optimization

I write a google apps script. it reads from a google sheet and sends emails to them based on how many quotas are left for one day. but I need to set a sleep timer to make my script sleep every 5 minutes. But I'm not sure which line I should add the time out or sleep function and how should I do it.

```
// It will only works on sheets with below schema:
// A      B          C          D         E         F           G
// ID   Email   First Name  Last Name   Status  Email Body  Email Subject

// DO NOT change any line of this code
// DO NOT change schema of your sheet or swap columns with each other (otherwise code may not work properly)
// Write your Email Body in "F2" cell and your Subject in "G2" cell
// To use rich text editor, use https://onlinehtmleditor.dev/ , then copy & paste ""HTML source code"" in "F2" cell

var EMAIL_SENT = 'SENT';
var EMAIL_ERROR = 'ERROR';


function sendEmails() {
    var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() - 1; // leave 1 for being sure
    Logger.log("Number of emails you can send in this run:" + emailQuotaRemaining);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var message = sheet.getRange(2, 6).getValue();
    var subject = sheet.getRange(2, 7).getValue();
    var startRow = 2;
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1; // Number of rows to process
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5);
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    var sentCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[1];
        var firstName = row[2].toString().trim();
        firstName = firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + firstName.slice(1); // Capitalize first name
        var status = row[4];
        var messageWithName = "<p>Dear " + firstName + "</p>" + message;
        if (status !== EMAIL_SENT && MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 1) { // Prevents sending duplicates AND check for remaining daily quotes
            var isFailed = false;
            try {
                MailApp.sendEmail({
                    to: emailAddress,
                    subject: subject,
                    htmlBody: messageWithName
                });
            } catch (error) {
                Logger.log(error);
                isFailed = true;
            }
            if (isFailed) {
                sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 5).setValue(EMAIL_ERROR);
                Logger.log(`something went wrong for sending to: ${emailAddress}`);
            }
            else {
                sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 5).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
                Logger.log(`successfully sent to: ${emailAddress}`);
                sentCount += 1;
            }

            // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
            SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        }
    }
    Logger.log(`${sentCount} emails has been sent successfully!`);
}
```

Comment: I guess you actually want a trigger that will wake up the function  every 5 minutes, if you are referring to script runtime quotas? If this is the case, check https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers

Comment: Why do you need to make it sleep? Do you need to bypass the maximum execution time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
function myNewTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendEmails")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(5)
  .create();
}
```

and launch one time.